# Python : How to return two values from function which is called from elif?

Tags: python-3.x, function, if-statement

The  `elif someother_function():`  here check if it is true and also need to print the returned value.
Can anyone help me with this?

```
def some_function():
     if correct:
         return True
     else:
         return False

def someother_function():
     if correct:
         return True,f
     else:
         return False,None


if some_function():
     print("something")
elif someother_function():
     print(f)
else:
     print("nothing")
```

Here, how to return f from someother_function to where it called at elif?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try:

```
def some_function(correct):
   if correct:
       return False
   else:
       return False

def someother_function():
    if correct:
       return True, f
else:
    return False, None

if some_function():
    print("something")
elif [x := someother_function()] and x[0]:
    print(x[1])
else:
    print("nothing")
```

Comment: Yeah, that helps. But i can not call someother_function before checking the some_function()  in my original program.

Comment: i was looking for something like, ```elif true_or_false in (true_orfalse,f=someother_function())```.

Comment: @ImageSchnell Or you can try `x := someother_function(True)` please take a look on my last edited

Comment: haven't seen this coding before, let me try.

Comment: I am sorry, I don't understand what you have done.

Comment: `x` is variable return from someother_function. `x[0]` is true_of_false. `x[1]` is f fuction

Comment: Can you share any program or links where this is using?

Comment: I am using python 3.6, I think  ```:= ```  is introduced in 3.8.

Comment: Oh, sorry i can not see a your python version on post

Answer (score 0):

If you want you can write a class with your functions and set a class variable with your output:

```
import random

class foo:
    
    def __init__(self):
        self.f=None
        
    def some_function(self):
        correct= random.choice([True, False])
        if correct:
            return True
        else:
            return False

    def someother_function(self):
        self.f = "something 2"
        correct= random.choice([True, False])
        if correct:
            return True,
        else:
            return False,None

if __name__=="__main__":
    temp = foo()
    if temp.some_function():
         print("something")
    elif temp.someother_function():
         print(temp.f)
    else:
         print("nothing")
```

Comment: Thanks, @Mazziotti, I was looking for more simple ways, guess I have to involve my class in this. No way to return two values to elif directly I guess.

Comment: Maybe the solution is simpler than we think

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to specify a sort of event. Check this code and try it if you want:

```
import random

event = random.choice([True, False])

def some_function(correct):
     if correct:
         return True
     else:
         return False

def someother_function(correct):
     if correct:
         return True, f
     else:
         return False, None


if event == True:
    some_function()
    print("something")
elif event == False:
    someother_function():
    print(f)
else:
    print("nothing")
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe not exactly what you want but you can turn your function into generator.

```
def some_function():
    return correct

def someother_function():
     if correct:
         yield True
         yield "A"
     else:
         yield False
         yield None
someother_function_gen = someother_function()


if some_function():
     print("something")
elif next(someother_function_gen):
     print(next(someother_function_gen))
else:
     print("nothing")
```

Comment: can't call ```someother_function_gen = someother_function()``` before checking the ```if some_function()```.